# Spring web application public static void main(String []args)

Tags: spring, java

Ответьте на такой вопрос. Есть спринг web проект с контроллерами, DAO там и другими элементами, который спокойно существует без `public static void main(String[] args)`.  Существуют ли случаи, когда надо использовать этот метод?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program к примеру этот туториал. Автор работает с RestTemplate через main(). Как насчет такого варианта?

Comment: Вобщем настроил я rest сервис на Spring. Сервис развернул на Tomcat. Потом подключил org.codehaus.mojo, который запустил внутри public static void main(String[] args) Rest клиент

Comment: может, такое на реальной практике и не встречается, да и откуда мне знать, на первую свою работу java программистом я еще не устроился.

Comment: @romashechka встречается, именно поэтому такие популярные servlet-контейнеры, как Tomcat и Jetty имеют встраиваемые варианты. Сам по себе ваш вопрос странный: что значит надо использовать этот метод? Вы сами решаете, какой метод использовать в зависимости от различных условий.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать, по своему усмотрению. Хоть десяток классов c `main()` создать. Когда это может потребоваться? Например, если веб-приложение и какие-нибудь утилиты имеют общую кодовую базу. Т.е. с одной кодовой базы собирается несколько артефактов. war-ник идет деплоиться на сервер, а jar-ники использутся где-то еще.

Comment: примерчик можно?

Comment: Spring boot активно использует этот метод

Answer (score 0):

В принципе main может использоваться для тестирования.

Comment: Для тестирования надо писать тесты, а не main методы